# EPPlus csv parsing ampersand("&") issue

Tags: c#, excel, csv, epplus

I´m using EPPlus LoadFromText to parse a csv into an excel file.

```
var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Delimiter = ';';
        format.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        format.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-pt");

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFilePath)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);

            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(fileName), format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None, false);
            package.Save();
        }
```

When a row has more than one column with an ampersand("&"):

001;David & Goliath;10;20;David & Goliath

The call throws an exception:
"An item with the same key has already been added".
Is there a way to avoid this problem without changing the input csv data?

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Are the downvotes because it is easy to parse the csv manually?

Comment: Perfectly valid question, and you got an upvote from me. IMHO your _shouldn't_ need to parse the CSV manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two parameter call works for me, so you may be able to use it as a workaround:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(
    new FileInfo(path), format
);
```

Note that the four parameter call in you example above is doing exactly the same thing.

So this *looks* like a bug. Taken directly from source code, the four parameter overload:

```
public ExcelRangeBase LoadFromText(string Text, ExcelTextFormat Format, TableStyles TableStyle, bool FirstRowIsHeader)
{
    ExcelRangeBase excelRangeBase = this.LoadFromText(Text, Format);
    ExcelTable excelTable = this._worksheet.Tables.Add(excelRangeBase, "");
    excelTable.ShowHeader = FirstRowIsHeader;
    excelTable.TableStyle = TableStyle;
    return excelRangeBase;
}
```

Is blowing up when trying to add the `ExcelTable` when there are ampersand(s) in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand will be escaped as `&amp;` in XML and you are using ';' as a delimiter.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why only the presence of a second ampersand would cause the issue. Still I changed the delimiter and still got the same exception.